# Python telnetlib telnet.write() dropping messages

Tags: python, telnet

Given the following code:

```
import telnetlib
import sys
def func1(IP,user,passw):
    t=telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
    t.write(user.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
    t.write(passw.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
    return t

def func2(t,command):
    t.write(command.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
    print(command)

user=sys.argv[1]
passw=sys.argv[2]
IP=sys.argv[3]
t=func1(IP,user,passw)
for i in range(6):
    func2(t, "message "+str(i))
```

By looking at the server and also Wiresharking it, only messages 1 and 2 gets through.

Now, if I change the `func2(t,command)` function as follows:

```
def func2(t,command):
    t.write(command.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
    t.read_eager()   #This is the new line.
    print(command)
```

It all works fine and all messages are been transmitted.

Any idea?

Python3.3 WindowsXP

Comment: For starters, your code contains a lot of syntax error. You can't use `pass` as a variable name, it's reserved. Also, you don't need brackets in your `for` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the text coming back to prevent the socket blocking.  This is why your other method works.

In a real world session you would always be reading back the results of logging in and of commands.

Comment: Your answer does not seem right. In other cases it works, if I am writing 10 `write` commands one after each other without reading (not in a function) , it works. Also, no documentation about what your saying.

Comment: Also, by looking at wireshark in cases that do work, I can see that it takes a number of `write()` commands, and deliver their content as one packet and not the same way coded in python, so why doesn't it happen in here?